# Need someone to figure out what I am doing wrong

Tags: python

```
a,b = input().split()

# a and b are in strings

for x in range(1,10):
   for y in range(2,10):
      if (x*y)*y == int(a+str(x)+b) :
        print(x,y)
else:
    print("No")
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I want to print out the value of x and y when (x*y)*y is equal to the number of `int("a"+str(x)+"b")`

I was expecting to get the values of x and y, but it prints out "No" every time even though when I printed out (x*y)*y and int(a+str(x)+b), they had the same answers.

Comment: Did you mean to abort the loop after `print(x, y)`?

Comment: Is that your real indentation?

Comment: Please add a reproducible example of what fails: what you input, the output and the expected output. That said, you probably wanted to stop whenever you get a result, which means breaking out of both loops.

Comment: The code as written will print the correct x,y if you give it a valid a,b. It will still print "No" even when it finds a match (because you aren't breaking out of the loop). For example, use "1 8" for the input makes a="1" and b="2" so when x=2 and y=8 we get (2*8)*8 = 128 and it prints "2 8"

Comment: So, a better way to do this would be to write your code as a function and RETURN (x,y) or "No" instead of printing them. You can always use "print(my_func())" afterwards.

Comment: What is the problem of using print instead of return? As long as you don’t do print(func()) I thought it would be fine

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if this is what you want, but if you put it in a function you can return the first values that match

```
a, b = input().split()

# a and b are in strings

def find_x_y(a, b):
    for x in range(1, 10):
        for y in range(2, 10):
            if (x*y)*y == int(a+str(x)+b):
                return x, y


print(find_x_y(a, b))
```

E.g. If I ran it with `1 5` it prints `(7, 5)`

Comment: Thank you. yes that works. 
However if I do a=4, b=1, it returns None (it should return 4,9). Why is that? 
4,1 should also work because both would be 441 and 441 when u calculate it

Comment: @YusukeZamma if `a=4` and `b=1`, then the answer would be `4` + random number + `1`. With your expected output of `4, 9`, we say x = 4 and y = 9. 4*9*9 = 324 so it wouldn't return given the inputs of `4 1`. If we pass in `1, 4` on the other hand, we get `(4, 6)` because the answer is 144.